# Can I use dropbox with a linux server that has no gnome/kde installed?

Tags: linux, dropbox

I want to sync files from my home directory on my linux server to my local computer. I noticed the instructions for dropbox.com only has instructions for linux with gnome/kde. can i use dropbox without a gui?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How To Install Dropbox In An Entirely Text Based Linux Environment <strike>[original link](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall)</strike> [mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20110725154912/http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall)
Dropbox Linux CLI <strike>[original link](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxLinuxCLI)</strike> [mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20101007113803/http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxLinuxCLI)

Comment: damn link rot...

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20101007113803/http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxLinuxCLI and http://web.archive.org/web/20110725154912/http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/TextBasedLinuxInstall I wonder why those smart heads removed such an useful info from their website...

Comment: Thank god someone saved their wiki making an unofficial one http://dropboxwiki.com/Welcome

Comment: Link rot is precisely why its a good idea to have self contained answers. Though in this case the archive.org mirror also has the python script in question...

Answer (score 0):

In the above link(s) you can find this shell script:

https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader

I've just configured and installed it, and can confirm that it works.